# Project backup along with database to removable drive

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans, backup

I am developing with netbeans.
I am using MySql database.
I want to move my project on my another laptop.
But when i copy my project to removable drive i don't get database files with project.
Please tell me how to move whole project along with database files.
I am copying from hard  disk, is that a problem???

Answer (score 0):

You could use the export function from the open-source program "MySQL Workbench" and then import it on your laptop.

MySQL Workbench: http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

And how to use MySQL Workbench to export & import:
https://www.beastnode.com/portal/knowledgebase/48/MySQL-Workbench-Backup-and-Import-your-MySQL-Database.html